# Is the norm a proper convex function?

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Norms are closed convex functions. Are they also proper convex functions?

Let $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ be a norm.
To prove it is proper, it is sufficient to say that, since
$$ \Vert 0 \Vert = 0$$, 
then at least there exists one $x$ (i.e 0) s.t. $\Vert x \Vert < +\infty$?

Or do I need something more?

Comment: norms are not proper convex. Take $0$ and any $x\neq 0$. Then $\|x/2\|=(\|0\|+\|x\|)/2$. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: What's your definition of "proper convex"?

Comment: An extended-real-valued function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{ 0 \}$  is said to be proper if there exist $x \in \mathbb R^n$  such that $f(x) \in \mathbb R$. 
Equivalently, the function  is not everywhere $+ \infty$ (and it is nowhere negative).

Did I get the definition wrong? We were talking about convex functions at lesson...